# Work with two usb keypads in Linux

Tags: linux, usb

I want to connect two usb keypads to the same computer. Then I want to open two consoles #1 and #2 and execute one process on each one of them. Then I want to receive input from keypad #1 on console #1 and input from keypad #2 on console #2.
How can this be achieved? Assume code is written in C. Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to migrate, because I think that this is off-topic for Stackoverflow; but I'm torn between flagging for migration to [Unix (and Unix-like OS-es) Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) and off-topic as 'belongs on [Super User](http://superuser.com/)'...

Comment: I'd migrate to Unix, since this is a Linux issue.

Comment: Sorry guys, I'm kind of new here. Should I migrate this question myself? delete and then ask on Unix?